# rails create element fail with wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I rencently take a "old" rails project

I run `bundle install` and give me arror with json 1.8.0 then fix it with `bundle update` and `bundle install`

Then run `rake db:schema:load`

And when I run `rake db:seed` give the error:

> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)

I detele all lines of seeds.rb  and put only one create and fail with the same error

Also open a console (rails console) and try two create with different models and fails

```
irb(main):002:0> Group.create( name: "Test" )
   (0.5ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:160:in `initialize'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:160:in `new'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:160:in `substitute_at'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_record/relation.rb:99:in `block in substitute_values'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_record/relation.rb:98:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_record/relation.rb:98:in `each_with_index'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_record/relation.rb:98:in `substitute_values'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_record/relation.rb:58:in `insert'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:521:in `_create_record'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_record/counter_cache.rb:139:in `_create_record'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:122:in `_create_record'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:306:in `block in _create_record'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:83:in `run_callbacks'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:306:in `_create_record'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:57:in `_create_record'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:501:in `create_or_update'
... 23 levels...
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:248:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:248:in `block in require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:233:in `load_dependency'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:248:in `require'
    from /home/inye/Escritorio/zembia/aiurveda/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `load'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `block in load'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:233:in `load_dependency'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Try updating rails to `4.2.7`. It seems like [a beta bug](https://gist.github.com/colinrymer/e35df80ea01cac20500c).

Comment: thx @max, problem solved. whoe do you find this? I google a lot.

Comment: I think i googled "activerecord-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:160:in `initialize'" if you take the file path and line number from the top line of the stack trace it often gives relevant results.

Comment: thx. you will post an aswer?

Comment: Since you solved it you can answer it yourself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution according with @max comment, was:

1. Change rails version in Gemfile

from `gem 'rails', '4.2.0.beta2'` to `gem 'rails', '4.2.7'`

2. run `bundle update rails`

and problem solved!